# Music Player controls in notification like spotify with flutter

Tags: android, iphone, flutter, notifications, android-notifications

Im using the "audioplayers" library to play music in flutter
I have the whole music player thing figured out
But i need a way to add a notification when a song is playing that has controls like a seekbar and a pause and play button, kinda like spotify

How would i go about implementing this in flutter

i tried looking into any libraries that already do this, but there aren't any libraries that adds advanced notifications with flutter